# Store does not get new ID after create

Tags: rest, extjs, extjs4.2

I have a editable grid with store + model + REST-Proxy.
Get, update and delete is no problem, but if I do:

```
store.insert(0, {});
cellEditing.startEditByPosition({
    row: 0,
    column: 1
});
```

the server respond with:

```
{
"success":true,
"results":0,
"root":"data",
"message":null,
"data":{"TerritoryUserPK":"7f064ddd-d5c9-47ae-94cc-29da14d27962"},
"debug":null
}
```

where "TerritoryUserPK" is the idProperty of the model.
I would now expect that the store will use this id for the new object, but it remains "ext-record-1".

How must the server response look like, so the Ext Store excepts the new ID?
The reader is this:

```
reader: {
    type: 'json',
    root: 'data',
    messageProperty: 'message',
    totalProperty: 'results'
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the problem, store.load() gets an object with metadata so that the root property of the reader gets set to `"rows"`. After the POST request the server respond with an object without metadata and the data in a `"data"` property. The reader remembers the last root property and will search for `"rows"` and cant find the property.

So be always aware of values set by metadata.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting a [`clientIdProperty`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.0/#!/api/Ext.data.Model-cfg-clientIdProperty) in your model, and return the id generated by ext back into the data...

For example, in your model:

```
clientIdProperty: 'clientId'
```

In your response:

```
data: [{id: 123, clientId: 'ext-record-1', ...}]
```

I don't remember if the client id is sent to the server in the configured `idProperty` (I think so) or the `clientIdProperty`... Inspect the browser request to be sure!

Comment: Doesn't help: Ext sends the clientIdProperty only to the server if multiple records are saved.
I try to debug the whole process, but I missed the point where a callback is added to the XHR request, where Ext should wait for the new ID...

Comment: Wild guesses often lose... If I understand your last comment, you say you lost track of the execution when the request left, right? In that case, your response lands back in the  [http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.0/source/Server.html#Ext-data-proxy-Server-method-processResponse](processResponse) method of the proxy. So you can put a breakpoint there and go on with your debugging. I think it will resolve in the reader... Good luck!